# plt.contour working with levels but contourf returns error

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a simple code to make me contours:

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(arr1,arr2)
plt.contour(X,Y,Z,[level1,level2,level3])
```

This works without issue as expected. Now, if I try to fill the contours using plt.contourf:

```
 plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,[level1,level2,level3])
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which
has no identity
```

Removing the level argument removes the error, but it is important that I have 3 different colors for each level so that is not a suitable fix. What's going on here? Thanks for your help, I've spent waay too long on this!

Comment: One cannot find out without [mcve]; that is a runnable code which produces the error you get.

Comment: Do you have `nans` in your data?